# __getattr__ for class atributes?

Tags: python, attributes, metaclass, magic-methods, getattr

For a class `Foo`,

```
class Foo:
    ...
```

is there a way to call a specific method whenever `Foo.XXX` (an arbitrary class attribute `XXX`, such as `bar`, `bar2`, etc.) is being resolved, but NOT whenever `Foo().XXX` (an arbitrary instance attribute) is resolved? To the best of my knowledge, overriding

```
def __getattr__(self, a):
    ...
```

applies to the second case only. I'd like to benefit from the fact that `__getattr__` for instances is called only when the corresponding attribute is not found. Does anyone know how this should be solved? I've read through [the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) and found nothing of relevance.

I don't particularly care what happens if someone tries to assign a value to any class or instance attribute of `Foo`.

##### The use case (to avoid XY):

Class `Foo` is a messenger. Instances of `Foo` are basically tuples with extra steps. However, there are special cases of `Foo`, which I'd like to store as class attributes of `Foo` (I managed that using a special decorator). However, the number of special cases of `Foo` is gradually growing while they differ very insignificantly. It would be very efficient code-wise for me to have this special function called whenever someone wants `Foo.SPECIAL_CASE_123`, because mapping from `"SPECIAL_CASE_123"` to the actual special case is very fast and very similar to mapping `"SPECIAL_CASE_456"` to the other corresponding special case.

Comment: A bit of additional clarity is needed: So given `foo = Foo()`, what should happen when attempting to assign to an instance, i.e `foo.XXX = some_value`?  In any case it appears that you are trying to intercept or modify [object attribute lookup](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup) to block a particular step (i.e. at the instance level).  It would also be greatly useful to explain your exact use case, as it's rare that this is needed (to avoid [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @metatoaster Thank you for concerning yourself with my question, I'll update the body.

Comment: Would be better if you can complete the example `class Foo:` by filling in the body (to show some attribute) and example code to access it via the class and the instance along with the expected behavior for the code.

Comment: Instead of implementing magic attribute lookup behavior, consider just writing a staticmethod or classmethod to manage these "special case" instances.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica As I said, their number is gradually growing and their bodies look nearly identical. I'd like to avoid creating duplicate code. I can legit distinguish between them just by taking the attribute name, querying three dictionaries, and return the merged result.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan: Yeah, but you can do all that with a single classmethod. You don't need to write a separate method for each special instance.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica As in `Foo.get_special_case(case_name)`? Yeah, that definitely would work. However, is it possible to call `Foo.special_case(case_name)` whenever `Foo.case_name` is retrieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a metaclass to define how classes behave. In specific, redefine the class' `__getattr__` to change how attributes missing on the class are handled:

```py
# The "Type of Foo"
class MetaFoo(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, item):
        return f"Dynamically handled: {item}"


class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
    REGULAR_CASE_22 = "Catch 22"

print(Foo.REGULAR_CASE_22)     # Catch 22
print(Foo.SPECIAL_CASE_123)    # Dynamically handled: SPECIAL_CASE_123
print(Foo().REGULAR_CASE_22)   # Catch 22
print(Foo().SPECIAL_CASE_123)  # AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'SPECIAL_CASE_123'
```

Note that certain attribute lookups, such as for special methods like `__add__`, will circumvent the metaclass attribute lookup.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up some of the outputs.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thanks for the heads up. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Fantastic! I had no idea you could extend `type` and specify a `metaclass`. Thank you Mr. Miyangi.

Comment: >  “Metaclasses are deeper magic than 99% of users should ever worry about. If you wonder whether you need them, you don’t (the people who actually need them know with certainty that they need them, and don’t need an explanation about why).”

    — Tim Peters.

I think what you're looking for are [class descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)

@u

Comment: @lonetwin: Descriptors only manage a single attribute.

Comment: @lonetwin Not to overestimate my understanding of the matter, but currently, I feel like I know why I need them.

Comment: Fully integrated into my codebase. I love it. I'm going to abuse metaclasses now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with `@classmethod`s:

```
class Foo:        
    @classmethod
    def XXX(self, a):
        return a
print(Foo.XXX('Hello World'))
```

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Comment: My bad if I did not specify that properly in my question body, but I meant `XXX` to be a general *anything*, not specifically `XXX`. I'll update that asap.